# child groups do not display in manage groups list

Tags: contacts, groups

I just installed 4.7.6 and have imported contacts into groups. When I go to manage groups, child groups do not display. When I go to send a new mailing, child groups are listed but don't seem to be connected to parent groups.

Answer (score 1):

My experience on 4.4 and 4.6 is that when I first go to Manage Groups the child groups are hidden under the parent group.  I need to click on the arrow to the left of the parent group name to see the child groups.

Is it different on 4.7.6?

Comment: I have this problem too. They were there but now they are not.....

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20934) which had not been resolved as of October 24, 2017.